# Why does is this Visual Studio Code command not working using the API's vscode.commands.executeCommand()?

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

I'm making a VS Code extension that works with another extension and uses one of its commands is available in the command palette. I tried running the command using this using VS Code's API `vscode.commands.executeCommand('test.helloWorld')`. However, it throws an error into the debug console:

```
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107950)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\a…\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20
    at s.h (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:107622)
    at s.g (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106522)
    at s.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:106422)
    at Object.executeCommand (c:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\api\node\extensionHostProcess.js:115:30829)
    at c:\Users\ekric\desktop\test\extension.js:26:20…
```

I've tried doing the same thing but with other commands but still the same error. I'm assuming the error is caused due to using a relative command such as: `test.helloWorld` instead of running a command like this: `extesion.test.helloWorld`. I don't know how I would make the command global. Here's my `extesion.js` file:

```
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
const vscode = require('vscode');

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed

/**
 * @param {vscode.ExtensionContext} context
 */
function activate(context) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "test" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with  registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('test.helloWorld', function () {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from test!!');
        
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('test.helloWorld')
          
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

I'm only using vanilla JavaScript for this extension. I'm new to VS Code extesion devolpment so help is greatly appreiacated!

Comment: You are trying to execute `test.helloWorld` in the function that registers that as a command so it is not surprising that it won't work before that function has finished.  Does `vscode.commands.executeCommand('test.helloWorld')` work after that function?

Comment: @Mark Yes that fixed ```test.helloWorld``` however it didn't fix the problem with the local vs. global commands. Another command I'm trying to use instead of just ```test.helloWorld``` does not work. It comes from a third-party extension and in the ```package.JSON``` file it says the command name ```codeRunner.runCode``` however that does not work. I did get an error message from running the third-party command saying it couldn't be found.